# Switching form EF4 to EF5 switching new to create

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Previously when using EF4 all my objects that were being added to the database followed (possibly incorrectly) the pattern

```
Poll oPoll = new Poll();
oPoll.Name = "My Special Poll Question";
context.AddToPolls(oPoll);
context.saveChanges();
```

However when I am making the switch to EF5 I need to make use of the create object instead.

```
Poll oPoll = context.Poll.Create();
oPoll.Name = "My Special Poll Question";
context.AddToPoll(oPoll);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Since I now have about 3,000 pages of code, I really would rather not do a find for all the new keywords nor go through hand by hand. Is there a nice elegant way (by tool or otherwise) to update this pattern to the new pattern for EF5?

Answer (score 4):

If you know the names of all the entities, you could do a global regex replace:

Say you had Poll, Vote and Person as types, you could replace:

```
(Poll|Vote|Person) (.+) = new .+\(\);
```

With

```
$1 $2 = context\.$1\.Create\(\);
```

That'd turn `Poll oPoll = new Poll();` into `Poll oPoll = context.Poll.Create();`

To add extra entity types you want to replace, just edit the first part of the regex.

Comment: @Aducci , regexes in general or this one in particular?

Comment: I would be too paranoid to run any regex expression that affects 3,000 pages of code.

Comment: @Aducci, a sensible concern - so what you'd do is use the "find all" in Visual Studio and copy the results out into a text file to examine the list of things it wants to change before actually making the change. I'd be more worried about things being missed than it changing things it shouldn't.

Comment: Always using source control :P but there are around 500 entities, probably not a wise idea to run a regex that large on it, some entity names will have objects of the same name (in different namespaces).